# What were the "n-drink Amy" (Amy's personas after drinking)?

Tags: character, brooklyn-nine-nine

In  *Brooklyn-99*, Amy's personality was undergoing radical change with alcohol. Gina, Amy's friend was calling that "one-drink Amy", "two-drink Amy" etc. Each of those "n-drink Amys" were different - for example "one-drink Amy" was a talker, "two-drink Amy" was a flirt, "three-drink Amy" was a bully etc.

What were all the n-drink Amy personalities?

Comment: One can hardly call Gina as *Amy's Friend*

Comment: @Vishwa I would say Gina is Amy's friend.  She's just not a very good friend in general.

Comment: Gina and Amy do care about each other, just that Gina is not a very easy person to be around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## There are 9 (that we know of)

Here's a quick list from wiki (which i think is reliable enough in this case because this cant really be messed up).

> One Drink: Spacey Amy
>
> Two Drinks: Loud Amy
>
> Three Drinks: "Amy Dance Pants"
>
> Four Drinks: Pervert Amy
>
> Five Drinks: Confident Amy
>
> Six Drinks: Lonely Amy
>
> Seven Drinks: Unknown
>
> Eight Drinks: Equestrian Amy
>
> Nine Drinks: Speaks French
>
> <sub><sup>*- [Amy Santiago - Brooklyn 99 Wiki](http://brooklyn99.wikia.com/wiki/Amy_Santiago)*</sup></sub>

Comment: this list is the same here: http://possiblestalker.tumblr.com/post/133761548565/the-santiago-drunkenness-scale-one-drink-amys-a

Comment: what was "Equestrian Amy" doing?

Comment: Minor correction: 8 so far. We don't know if the writers will come up with more n-drink Amys (Amies?)

Answer (score 3):

In the most recent episode Amy revealed that 9 drink Amy speaks French

Comment: Nice catch, then. Though if you could [edit] in a clip or a quote, that'd make for an even better answer :)

Comment: I think this should be edited into the existing answer, rather than an answer in its own right.